# Set a cookie through Apache HTTP Client Fluent interface

Tags: java, http, cookies, apache-httpcomponents

I want to do this:

```
Content result = Request
    .Get("url.com")
    .addHeader("CookieName", "CookieValue") // is this the proper way ?
    .execute()
    .returnContent();
```

with `org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request`. Which is a part of [Apache HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org/).

I can't seem to find it in the docs, sorry about that and thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
//cookieStore.addCookie();
Executor executor = Executor.newInstance();
executor.cookieStore(cookieStore)
        .execute(Request.Get("/stuff"))
        .returnContent();
```

Comment: The method "cookieStore" is now deprecated.  Instead it should be: .use(cookieStore) as mentioned here   https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/fluent-hc/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/fluent/Executor.html#use(org.apache.http.client.CookieStore)